Normalization of absorbance data by fresh weight of samples
A [protocol] says

For each sample the absorbance (Abs) reading was divided by the fresh weight of the sample in grams. The results were normalized using an arbitrary value of 1 for the control genotype (1 = 0.14 absorbance units per gram fresh weight).

My data -
Genotype    Replicate   Absorbance  Fresh Weight (grams)
   G1          1          0.161               0.2167
   G1          2          0.203               0.2251
   G1          3          0.127               0.2497
   G2          1          0.194               0.2512
   G2          2          0.154               0.1987
   G2          3          0.3                 0.2
   G3          1          0.271               0.2013
   G3          2          0.213               0.2111
   G3          3          0.374               0.1857
   G4          1          0.382               0.2326
   G4          2          0.26                0.225
   G4          3          0.188               0.2012

What is the rationale for using an arbitrary value of 1=0.14 for normalization? How should I select this for my data or randomly define 1= any fraction? What does the final formula look like? Absorbance value * arbitrary value/fresh weight?
